# How do I not generate the default endpoints when using attribute routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using attribute routing in a Web API controller (.NET Framework 4.5.2 - don't ask, I'm trying to get approval for time to move everything forward).

I have applied a [RoutePrefix] attribute to my ApiController.

I have two controller actions, both HttpGets. Each has a [Route] attribute applied.

I'm using Swagger to auto-generate docs. In the docs for this controller I see three endpoints listed - two for my controller actions, and another HttpGet with the bare controller route.

That is what I have is this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test/Tickets")]
public class TestTicketsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetTickets()
    {
        ....
    }
    [HttpGet, Route("since")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetTicketsSince(string since)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

And In the generated Swagger docs I see three endpoints:

- GET api/test/Tickets
- GET api/test/Tickets/since
- GET api/TestTickets

This third endpoint, `api/TestTickets`, seems to be derived from the class name of the controller, ignored my routing attributes. And when I call it, I get an HTTP 200 with an empty body, despite not having defined an action for it.

Where is this coming from? And how can I stop it from being generated?

===

It was suggested that I remove the `[HttpGet, Route("")]` attribute. If I do, I get an error:

```
 Multiple operations with path 'api/TestTickets' and method 'GET'.
```

It was also suggested that I include my WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "swagger_root",
            routeTemplate: "",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: null,
            handler: new RedirectHandler((message => message.RequestUri.ToString()), "api/docs/index"));

        var mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
        formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(mediaType);

        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(formatter);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

If I comment-out the `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute`, the extra endpoint goes away.

Now it's just a matter of determining whether we have any controllers that expect this default endpoint to be there.

Thanks.

Comment: If you delete the `Route` attribute from `GetTickets`, do you still get the same result inside swagger?

Comment: Hi Jeff, as a .net framework api this would have been scaffold with a WebApiConfig file in App_Start folder, can you include it in your question please?

Comment: Do you still have the default route defined in the routing config, as well as the call to enable attribute routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[abdulg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3280464/abdulg) pointed out in a comment, rather than in an answer - default routes are configured in WebApiConfig.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```